# Order step metrics in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I´m working on a rather long Transformation in Kettle and I put some Steps in the middle of the Flow.
So now my Step metrics are all scrambled up and very hard to read.
Is there any way i could sort this to be in order (with the direction of the flow) again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps are stored in the order of insertion.  The step metrics grid allows the steps to be shown in a different order by clicking on the column header, but since a transformation graph can be meshed, it's generally not possible to sort the steps in the order of the data flow.  Only a single path in your graph could be sorted by analyzing the hops, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on # in a "Step metrics" tab it will sort the steps by their order. The visualisation in a "Metrics" tab will be also sorted.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is change the name of each step and add a number in front of it. Then sort by name.

Boring, I know, but it is what we have...

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunate that assigning a step number isn't an option. And maybe it differs by version, but in 8.3 the step metrics # column assignment seems to be somewhat based on the step's order in the flow (which of course breaks down when the flow branches), not by when the step was added. It does ring a bell that it was based on when the step was added in past versions though.

It's also unfortunate that the sort by step name is case sensitive - so steps that start with "a" come after steps that start with "Z". Perhaps there's a way to work that behavior into a naming strategy that actually leverages that for some benefit, but I haven't found one.

So I'm inclined to agree with @recacon - using a number prefix for the step names and then sorting execution metrics by step name seems like the best option. I haven't done much of this yet since without having a team standard it's unlikely to be maintained.

For the few times I have done it, I've used a three digit numeric prefix where values are lowest at the start of the flow and increase farther down the path. To reduce the need for re-sequencing when steps are added later, I start out incrementing by ten from one step to the next, then use a number between when splitting hops later on.

I also increment the 100's digit for branches in the flow or if there's a significant section of logic for a particular purpose.